# MozBackup for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, chromium

A silly question really, but is there something like [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/)(1) for Google Chrome/Chromium?

(1) - it is a little tool which picks up your Firefox settings (settings, passwords, bookmarks, browsing history ... everything really) and saves it in a file, so you can restore those settings after, let's say, a system reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they [one-upped that](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139).

> You can save your bookmarks, extensions, theme, and browser preferences to your Google Account so that they can be accessed across multiple computers.

(It syncs between computers and the cloud so once it finishes syncing, you can feel safe to nuke your system. Twice. With a sledgehammer. And your data should still be safe in Google's loving but slightly nosy arms.)

Comment: Uhmm, what does it mean to "one-upp that"? ... In any case, thanks. Nice description (No, I don't like it either) :)

Comment: To one-up something: to do better than something--to go a step above and beyond something

Comment: @Force Flow - I see. Thanks ('tis really the first time I heard that phrase).

Comment: Doesn't firefox have firefox sync? Either that, or I have some really benign spyware...