# backing up Google Chrome's click history to transfer to another computer

Tags: google-chrome, backup, browser, history

I want to be able to transfer Google Chrome's click history, that is, I want the Chrome installation in my new computer to show the links (for example, google search results) that I have visited previously in my current computer, as clicked. Backing up of the history list in this computer would also be nice, but not absolutely required. For Firefox I have used Mozbackup; I suppose what I need is something similar. I have seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/216024/mozbackup-for-google-chrome), but it is not what I am looking for. I need to be able to transfer these settings from USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Web History can be set up to track things other than just search](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-let-google-watch-over-your-web.html). If you're using Internet Explorer, install the Google Toolbar (only available for Internet Explorer) which will then submit all the URLs you access to Google Web History. If you're using Chrome, all of the features of Google Toolbar are already built into it.

[Signing in to Chrome brings your bookmarks, history, and other settings to all your devices](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/signin.html). Anything you update on one device instantly updates everywhere else, and your Chrome stuff is safe in case anything happens to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Google Sync features will help you. However, if you want transfer full data of google chrome, maybe Browser Transfer application in microsoft store helps you.
https://youtu.be/j_5VjNI9ChY

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Browser Transfer application maybe useflul, https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9PP4M2NK8PC8.

They promise to transfer all as https://youtu.be/AWtpvXB5HsU

Comment: Maybe a summary of its feature posted here would be better than the link to a video.